# How to filter data with checkbox in Vuejs with API?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, checkbox, axios

I would like to filter data in table using checkbox and outoput data will be shown based on checked/unchecked, for example when i'm checked "Show All" will ouput all data, and when i'm unchecked then output only will show some data. but when i'm trying to do this, the result nothing changed when i'm checked

here for vue html:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxOrder" v-model="checkedValue" value="Onloading Complete" >
  <label for="checkboxOrder">Show All</label>
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>code</th>
      <th>price</th>
      <th>status</th>
      <th>transporter</th>
      <th>driver</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, index) in showOrderDetail" :key="index">
        <td >{{Number(index)+1}}</td>
        <td>{{item.code}}</td>
        <td>{{formatNumber(item.invoice_price)}}</td>
        <td :class="statusBackground(item)">
          <template v-if="item.t_tour">
            <span v-if="!_.isEmpty(item.t_tour.t_tour_detail)"> 
                {{item.t_tour.t_tour_detail[0].status}}
            </span>
            <span v-else>Unproccess</span>
          </template>
          <span v-else>Unproccess</span>
        </td>
        <td class="bg-warning">{{item.m_transporter ? item.m_transporter.name : 'unproccess'}}</td>
        <td>{{driver(item)}}</td>
        <td><span class="btn btn-primary" @click="showModal(item.t_tour)"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and my vue.js :

```
import axios from "axios";
import accounting from "accounting";
import ShowTourDetail from "~/pages/transaction/order/ShowTourDetail";
export default {
  props: {
    rowData: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    rowIndex: {
      type: Number
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      t_order_detail: {},
      checkedValue:[]
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData();
  },
  computed:{
    showOrderDetail(){
      if(!this.checkedValue.length)
        return this.t_order_detail
      return this.t_order_detail.filter(o => this.checkedValue.includes(o.t_tour.t_tour_detail[0].status))
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchData() {
      this.t_order_detail = {
        ...(
          await axios.get(`/api/order-details`, {
            params: { t_order_id: this.rowData.id }
          })
        ).data
      };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply change method like :

```
<input type="checkbox" :value="mainCat.merchantId" id="mainCat.merchantId" v-model="checkedCategories" @change="check($event)">
```

Methos like:

```
 methods: {
    check: function(e) {
        if(e.target.checked){
          console.log("load all data using service");
          // service call here
        }else{
          console.log("load required data using service");
           // service call here
       }
        
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks, it's works but when first time load table nothing value show and i must checked/unchecked first to showing the value there

Comment: If it's useful, please accept the code and marked useful. thanks @srxctalia